# Character encoding problem in a web apps form submissions

Tags: php, character-encoding

I have a website that accepts user submissions to a forum from different locales, English and Swedish are the current "supported" locales. The most common language on the forums are in Swedish and that is where I encounter the intermittent problem of character encoding.

Could it be that some browsers are sending me ISO 8859 encoded strings but the page is encoded in utf-8 (and should be submitted in that encoding?). My php serverside is guessing the encoding with stuff like mb_detect_encoding but that doesn't seem to help.

I have this code to "guess" the encoding

```
if ( mb_detect_encoding($str, 'UTF-8, ISO-8859-1') == 'ISO-8859-1') {
    return mb_convert_encoding($str, 'UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1');
}
return $str;
```

on the submissions. Other encoding options are not an issue for this particular problem.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Make sure that the form page sets UTF-8 explicitly (by sending a `Content-Type` header), `<meta http-equiv` doesn't always work

Comment: @German yes the page definitely states UTF-8 by http, html attributes  and meta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser may send data in any character encoding, regardless of the character encoding of your HTML page. It should advertise the used encoding in the Content-Type header. You can use the [`accept-charset` Atrribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-accept-charset) on the `form` to specify which character encodings you want to receive.

Comment: I did do that in the apache config, is there a php.ini directive?

Comment: I am not talking about the Accept-Charset HTTP header, but about the `accept-charset` attribute of the `form` tag. The HTTP Header is a *request header*, that is sent by the browser to the server to indicate the charset of the response. It does not have any effect when the server sends it to the browser.

Answer (score 3):

> Could it be that some browsers are sending me ISO 8859 encoded strings but the page is encoded in utf-8

If you are serving the page containing the form with a `Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8` header, that should not happen, with certain caveats:

- If the user saves the page containing the form and submits it from the saved version, the header information will be lost so you will get the browser's guessed encoding which may be wrong. In this case you can add a `<meta>` version of the header to the page as well, so that it retains the information when saved to disc.
- If the user deliberately changes encoding from the View menu, this typically causes the form to submit in the user's (wrong) override encoding. This is pretty rare if you have served the page right to begin with, but a `<form accept-encoding="utf-8">` attribute can alleviate the problem a little... except that it doesn't work right in IE. So it's not a cure-all.
- If the user uses some custom non-browser app to submit their form data, all bets are off.

I think your attempt to detect encoding by trying UTF-8 first is about the best you can do if you really can't control the submission encoding. `mb_detect_encoding` is a bit weak in that it allows some byte sequences that aren't quite valid UTF-8 (the ‘overlongs’), but the idea is sound.

Comment: I was reasoning along these ideas. but i prefer the idea that browsers tries to impose their own CE. still not tested though. +1 and thanks.